# Unable to connect to AS400

Tags: .net, ibm-midrange

When I am trying to connect to AS400 using C#.NET, it's giving me error:

> > IBMDA400 is not registered on local Machine

Can anyone please explain me about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the provider you're using, IBM's  Client Access needs to be installed.  The OleDbProvider for IBM is included inthe Client Access package.

A better solution would be to use the [IBM for .Net](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.dndp.doc/htm/frlrfIBMDataDB2DB2ConnectionClassTopic.htm) provider.

If you have Client Access installed on the machine, you can get at the .Net provider by going into selective setup and choosing the .Net provider in the developer tools.